How to find linear dependence mod 2 in python
I have a n+1 by n matrix of integers. I want to find a linear combination of the rows that reduces to zero mod 2. How would I do this in python? I could write gaussian elimination on my own, I feel there ought to be a way to do this using numpy or other library without writing it from scratch. Example:
I have the matrix
[1, 3, 0]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 5]
The function should return [1, 0, 1, 1]. Because that linear combination yields [2,4,6] = [0,0,0] mod 2.

[0, 0, 0, 0] and [1, 1, 0, 0] (and many others) are also solutions. Why would you specifically want [1, 0, 1, 1]? I'm also curious about the use for this, would you care to explain?

I just want any non-zero solution. The reason I am doing this is because its a subroutine in the quadratic sieve factoring algorithm which I'm implementing as part of a project.

Is there anything you might find useful in these Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531503/gaussian-elimination-in-modulo-2-python-code , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70157819/linear-independence-of-vectors-in-modular-arithmetic-mod-2-using-python , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287398/finding-null-space-of-binary-matrix-in-python

Does this answer your question? Linear independence of vectors in modular arithmetic mod 2 using Python

You can use galois:
from galois import GF2
import numpy as np

A = [[1, 3, 0], 
     [1, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 5]]

A = GF2(np.array(A).T % 2)
print(A.null_space())

It gives:
[[1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1]]

The rows are a basis of the null space of the matrix over the field F_2.

Using the sympy package seems to be the easiest solution. I found the answer to this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70158227/19943103

It's best to just mark this question as a duplicate of that one.
